# Is it beneficial to move on cloud with constant/less varying load running 24x7?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, migration, cloud

I have OTM stack(Oracle transport manager - web,app, Db tier) running on 20 linux servers in colo on premise. This infra run 24x7 with load varying from 50-80% over the year. When I did the cost estimation of same infra on AWS(3 years RI), the cost is coming 2-3 times than my current hosting cost. So will it really beneficial to moving on cloud? Is there any thumb rule to make this decision?

Comment: The question has to be categorized as very broad, and most likely is unsuitable for stackoverflow.. But just on the cost perspective, AWS allows you can scale elastically, i.e you dont need to have the 20 servers all the time.. you can configure scaling based on traffic, i.e instances will be provisioned on demand and removed when the traffic slow downs. You also have the option of using spot instances.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Anyone is having such decision dilemma just need guidance and doesn't expect exact answers also can not post every detailed requirement. Just expecting the helpful points on which i should do research and some analysis. I hope many of getting this questions and will helpful for them to draw outline.

Comment: There is also many pits and traps for cloud or not to cloud.  There also "reserved instance" that cost 50% less than typical instance, but there is also hidden cost of particular services. You need to spends many weeks to gather the appropriate costing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage and server cost of a cloud services is NEVER cheaper than a flat N-tier server co-lo. In addition, you need to get a few devops engineer trained to interact with the services.

You should view moving to a cloud as different magnitude and perspective to your services : e.g. business continuity and high availability,etc factor which is costly to build your own in co-lo.

1. High availability
   Building such infrastructure is costly.

   - HA Server : (physical server with redundancy), pretty costly.
   - Internet service availability : you need to subscribe to multiple lines
   - you need to deploy server to different co-lo
2. Backup and disaster recovery

   - You need backup software and whole chunks of backup storage
   - You need your own backup hardware or subscribe to data center backup services due to huge data set.
   - You need subscribe services that move your backup to different storage facility.
   - You need to simulate recovery process in various data center
3. Server expansion cost

   - A SAN and NAS hardware must be provision at least 3 to 5 years ahead.
   - Extending CPU is difficult
4. Server Maintenance cost.

   - A lots of hardware vendors charge premium 15%~25% warranty base on hardware cost after the warranty period.
   - Lots of different hardware driver that is not compatible
   - Migration downtime cost
5. Consolidate server/services/apps licenses

   - Some apps/services license might charge you per CPU instead of cores. It is more expensive if you scale-out(more server ) , than ready a server with scale-up capability(more cores than CPU). But this also means spending in advance.

After you account of most of the above, you will notice the co-lo are getting closer to AWS.